# XpsDocumentWriter WriteAsync(DocumentPaginator) Save as modal dialog

Tags: c#

I am using WriteAsync(DocumentPaginator) method present in XpsDocumentWriter class in C# to print an xps file. This method internally opens a 'Save as' Dialog where user can provide the name of the XPS file. However this 'Save as' dialog is a modeless dialog. Is there any way to make the 'Save as' Dialog as modal dialog? My intention is not to allow the user to switch to any other window while the 'Save as' dialog is open still.